# Can I automate a Cognos report to run based on a calculated month end date compared to the report run date

Tags: automation, cognos

My company operates based on a 4-4-5 fiscal period and therefore the end of the month always falls on a Friday but generally does not fall on the last day of the month calendar.  I can pull in the last day of the month utilizing a query that gives me all the fiscal month end dates from the table.  I need to set the report up to automatically run every Sunday and compare the the previous Friday's date to see if it exists in the month end date query result set.  If the date does not fall in the result set, the report should not run.  If it does, it should run and will be e-mailed to the necessary recipients.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have captured the month end dates within a SQL query named "PD Ending/Run Dates".  I just don't know how, or if, it's possible to have the report check to see if the current date (Sunday) minus 2 days (to calculate the previous Friday's date) falls within the query result and allow the report to run.  Here would be an example for February 2023 and the expected action.  The report would be set to run each Sunday, using GETDATE() then subtract 2 days (calculating the previous Friday's date) and then compare if that date falls in the query result (M/E Date).  If it does, the report runs.

```
Sun Run Date     Prev Fri Date     M/E Date    Action
2/5/23           2/3/23            2/24/23     None
2/12/23          2/10/23           2/24/23     None
2/19/23          2/17/23           2/24/23     None
2/26/23          2/24/23           2/24/23     Run Report
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for Event Studio.

Create an Event Studio Agent that includes a query that returns the maximum last Friday of the month before today, and a task to run the report and email the results.  Configure the agent to perform tasks only when the query results change.

Schedule the agent to run every Sunday.

When the agent runs, it will compare the result of the query to the results from the previous run.  If the results changed -- meaning a new "last Friday of the month" date appears in the results -- the report will run and be emailed.

Comment: Thanks.  I will give that a try.  I haven't used Event Studio so that will be a new learning opportunity :-)